# connect the scale weight via SR232

Tags: python, serial-port, scale, putty

I recently purchased an XFOC+ Gram scale with an RS-232 connection, and I am having trouble connecting it to my PC. I have a cable that goes from RJ12 to USB, which seems to be suitable for the connection. However, when I attempt to connect the device to my PC, it appears that the scale is not sending any data.

My goal is to connect the scale using a Python code, but even though the code appears to be functioning correctly, I am not receiving any data from the scale. I have also attempted to connect using other software such as Putty or Hercules, and while the connection is established, no data is being transmitted.

Moreover, I have found that the manual lacks sufficient information. It suggests performing certain operations that the scale does not seem to support. I am in need of assistance to determine whether the scale is indeed sending data or not. Can you explain how I should set the scale for continuously sending data?

scale weigth link: [text](https://gram-group.com/product/gram-xfoc-plus/)

cable link: [text](https://www.amazon.it/DSD-TECH-SH-RJ12B-Seriale-RS232/dp/B09P8D5WL9/ref=sr_1_1_sspa?adgrpid=130610399027&hvadid=591546565833&hvdev=c&hvlocphy=20582&hvnetw=g&hvqmt=e&hvrand=13197753444715684170&hvtargid=kwd-301482963336&hydadcr=15918_2272054&keywords=rj11+to+usb&qid=1688577346&sr=8-1-spons&sp_csd=d2lkZ2V0TmFtZT1zcF9hdGY&psc=1)

i think the scale doen't send any data. I share with you the manual.[text](https://gram-group.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/MU_XFOC_ENG_ESP_FRA_DEU_001.pdf)

Comment: This is probably the manual you should look at. [XFOC+ / XFOC+ PLU / XFOC+ RS PLU Operation Manual](https://gram-group.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/05/MU_XFOC_ESP_ENG_FRA_PRT_DEU_003.pdf) In the English version, there seems to be an explanation of the setting operation on page 10. However, it seems that there is no description of the communication protocol specification there either. It is better to ask the reseller or manufacturer to disclose the communication protocol specifications.